# Why undefined property when foreach collection?

Tags: laravel, relationship

```php
$conversations = Conversations::with('bulletin', 'messages')->leftJoin('own', 'conversations.bulletin_id', '=',
    'own.id')
    ->select('conversations.*')
    ->where('owner_id', $userId)
    ->orWhere('owner', $userId)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
dd($conversations);

$conversation = Conversations::getInfo($conversations->first());

foreach ($conversations as $conversation) {
    dd($conversation->bulletin);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1dy.png - screenshot with first dd()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGAHg.png - screenshot dd() in foreach() - nothing here

If I try to access to `$conversation->bulletin->id` this will be error 'undefined property...'

```php
public static function getInfo($conversation)
{
    $conversation->messages = self::find($conversation->id)->messages();
    $conversation->bulletin = self::find($conversation->id)->bulletin();
    $conversation->users = self::find($conversation->id)->users();

    return $conversation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because for some `$conversations` or may be one of the `$conversation` doesn't have any `bulletin`. As a result when you loop through all the `$conversations` and access `$conversion->bulletin->id` that one `conversation` cause the error. When you run `dd` it only dump the first `conversation` and die. As a result you are not seeing correctly what is the problem.

replace the following line:

`dd($conversation->bulletin);`

with this line and see:

`dump($conversation->id, $conversation->bulletin);`

I am quite sure you will see at least one conversation doesn't have any bulletin.

**Update:**

self::find($conversation->id)->users(); will return the relationship object, not the collection of users. If you want access on collection of user then you should do `self::find($conversation->id)->users`. Same for `bulletin` and `messages`

Actually, I don't think you need this `getInfo()` method. You just need to use the `with` method of query properly,

So, replace:

`Conversations::with('bulletin','messages')`

this part by `Conversations::with('bulletin','messages',`users`)`

Comment: you're right, but problem not in table data because all conversations have bulletins - checked manually.

Comment: I have `$conversation = Conversations::getInfo($conversations->first());` between query and foreach, when I comment this line then all ok. How it can crash my code? :)) first() saving $conversations?

Comment: No idea what you are doing inside the `getInfo()` method. Besides, you question doesn't reflect this issue.

Comment: This code is not readable. Please updated the question including this code.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: it works now, as I understand it will retrieve all data in one query? With getInfo method I wanted to get full data only for first conversation and not to other conversations. Did you think better create two queries - one for all and other one for full data set only one conversation? It works fast now, but im worring what happend when conversations will have million rows.